# How can I make a multiplayer variable, so when someone adds one everyone's screen shows the variable (+1)?

Tags: python, variables, cloud, real-time-multiplayer

I am trying to make a project that requires a multiplayer variable. For example, if I made a variable called "x" and someone said `x += 1` then everyone's x would be one more. Could someone please tell me if there is some kind of module that can do this, or if it is impossible?

Thank you

Comment: What you are asking for doesn't really make sense. What do you mean by "someone said `x += 1` ?? What do you mean by "everyone's x"?

Answer (score 0):

well you can use a class like so...

```
class Myclass:
   x = 0
```

now when you do Myclass.x + 1

Myclass.x will equal 1 for everyone that uses Myclass.x.

You could also use global variable.

Also what do you mean by everyone. Are they all going to be having their own process of the application running? You could just do math on variables in a shared .txt document or something like...

to read x you could do ...

mytext.txt

```
x=100
```

code.py

```
def readx():
    with open('mytext.txt', 'r') as fp:
        data = fp.readlines()

    x = 0
    for line in data:
        if line.startswith('x'):
            value = line.split('=')[1] # [0] = x [1] = 100
            x = int(value)

    print(x) # 100
```

and to change x you can do ...

code.py

```
def writex(value):
    with open('mytext.txt', 'w') as fp:
        fp.write(f'x={value}')
```

so you can have something like...

input = int('Type here: ') # output: Type here:

## Friends console

output: Type here: x += 1

you just write the input into the text file

writex(input)

and x+=1 value gets written to first like of the text.txt file etc.

or you could use sockets and so on.

You could also use global variable.